# How to decode Magellan URL coordinates to lat/lon

Tags: convert, coordinate-system

Magellan uses this URL to designate a coordinate in New York:

```
mgn:///address/?coord=merwFvlqbM,name=Viva%20Herbals%20Pizzeria,number=179,street=2nd%20Avenue,city=New%20York,country=US
```

How can I decode the "coord" part (`merwFvlqbM`) of the URL? It looks like an encoded latitude longitude value. Other NY coords have similar values:

glp **wF** |fs **bM**

ubr **wF** r~p **bM**

(common characters bold)

Comment: Can you try to get 2 encoded coordinates where only the latitude changes? And give the distance between those points.

Comment: @johanvdw: 49°0'1"N / 100°0'10"W is qkajH~xjaR. 43°0'0" N / 100°0'17"W is _mmeGzckaR. Does this help you? It's hard to get exact coordinates using a touch UI.

Comment: Well, it's not [geohashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash), but i suspect something similar.  Could you generate a coordinate for 0,0 90,180 and post the result?

Comment: @Geoist: Unfortunately the app only lets me generate URLs for locations within the US. Wanna have a specific one?

Comment: whats the app you're using?

Comment: This is as far as I got.  For the life of me, I cant get any kind of correlation between the numbers.  I've tried heaps of permutations.  Also, little endian / big endian.. etc.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AhcbR9vn0TbfdGdPdmlmVGRkcV9tTlJ0anBJSmY3YUE

Comment: @Geoist: Wow, appreciate your effort! The app is called Magellan Roadmate for iPhone. What I found so far is that not all 8-bit characters are used. I assume only 64. Also, the first half looks like it encodes latitude, the second half longitude. Using a trick I was able to produce some out-of-US values, unfortunately this only works for areas with POIs: London, near the 0 Meridian (`_myxHlsk@`, `okyxHdzk@`), Singapore, near the equator (`oagG}htxR`, `apgGifvxR`), Antarctica (hol`M t}|rM). Notice that for London & Singapore, there are only 9 chars not 10, probably because of the 0 lat / lon!

Comment: Here are some more reference coords (lat,lon): 6.450006,-2.116671: `owjf@dl|CK`, 6.157536,0.059781: `qsqd@stJ`, 6.163083,0.037250: `gvrd@ygF`.

Comment: I'll have another crack at it, but I'm guessing they've done something obscure.  It doesn't take much, and I'm no crypto expert.